# std::string.substr Run Time Error

Tags: c++, string, c++11, vector, std

I've been working on a program to balance chemical equations. I had it so it split the equation into two sides based upon the `=`. I was working on my program and I did something, now I'm getting a run time error when I attempt to set the first index of `std::vector<std::string>` to the `substr` of my equation. I need help figuring this out.

```
std::vector<std::string> splitEquations(std::string fullEquation)
{
    int pos = findPosition(fullEquation);
    std::vector<std::string> leftAndRightEquation;
    leftAndRightEquation.reserve(2);
    leftAndRightEquation[0] = fullEquation.substr(0, (pos)); //!!!! Error
    leftAndRightEquation[1] = fullEquation.substr( (pos+1), (fullEquation.size() - (pos)) );
    removeWhiteSpace(leftAndRightEquation);
    std::cout << leftAndRightEquation[0] << "=" << leftAndRightEquation[1] << std::endl;
    return leftAndRightEquation;
}
```

Here's my code for `findPosition`.

```
int findPosition(std::string fullEquation)
{
    int pos = 0;
    pos = fullEquation.find("=");
    return pos;
}
```

Comment: `reserve` doesn't actually create any new elements.

Comment: Side note: Why are you using a vector instead of two variables?

Comment: @Cameron Because later I have to perform some operations on them and I thought it'd be better practice to write a loop instead of the same code twice with the exception of the variable.

Comment: So what happens if findPosition() returns that it cannot find the string?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie , I don't think I should have that problem. The only way for my program to get to the stage where it requires findPosition ()  I haven't gotten into exception handling yet. I'll post the code to my original question and you can tell me what you think. To be honest,  I haven't even thought about that.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Finally added it to my question. Is there anything wrong with how I'm doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Member function `reserve`

```
leftAndRightEquation.reserve(2);
```

of class `std::vector` does not create elements of the vector. It simply reserves memory for elements that will be added to the vector in future.

So as the vector has no elements you may not use the subscript operator. Instead of it you have to use member function `push_back`
ALso the second substring can be specified simpler.

```
leftAndRightEquation.push_back( fullEquation.substr( 0, pos ) );
leftAndRightEquation.push_back( fullEquation.substr( pos + 1 ) );
```

Member function `substr` of `class std::basic_string`  is declared the following way

```
basic_string substr(size_type pos = 0, size_type n = npos) const;
```

that is it has two parameters with default arguments.

If you want to use the subscript operator then you initially should create the vector with two elements. You can do it the following way

```
std::vector<std::string> leftAndRightEquation( 2 );
```

And after that you may write

```
leftAndRightEquation[0] = fullEquation.substr( 0, pos );
leftAndRightEquation[1] = fullEquation.substr( pos + 1 );
```

Comment: Thanks for the simplification of my second `substr`. I didn't realize the difference between `reserve` and `resize`.

Answer (score 2):

The error is not on `substr`, it's on the vector's `operator[]`. At the time when you try assigning at indexes zero and one, the vector is still empty. It has two spots *reserved* for expansion, if needed, but the size of its "active area" is zero; accessing it causes the error.

You can use `push_back` to fix the problem, like this:

```
leftAndRightEquation.push_back(fullEquation.substr(0, (pos)));
leftAndRightEquation.push_back(fullEquation.substr( (pos+1), (fullEquation.size() - (pos)) ));
```

Answer (score 1):

change`reserve()` to `resize()`, it'll work. In all other cases, the `reserve()` call does not cause a reallocation and and the vector capacity is not affected, but `resize()` does.